# Spring boot pass OAuth2 credential to OpenFeign client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, openfeign

I'm having 2 services: service A (spring boot and `openfeign` for http client) and service B. My services are behind a gateway (APISIX), which is integrated with keycloak. Both services are configured OAuth2 to expose to public.

There is a use case, when a `logged in` user requests to service A, and service A requests to service B using `openfeign`. What is the proper way to pass OAuth2 credential to OpenFeign client when requesting to service B?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked a first Google result: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-feign-oauth-token ?

Comment: I do. The problem here is I don't know how to get the OAuth2 token inside openfeign interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you're on a [resource-server](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers) and want to issue a request from that resource-server on behalf of the authenticated user, you should be able to
access the Bearer token from the `Authentication` instance in the security-context.

Default `Authentication` types are `JwtAuthenticationToken` for resource-servers with JWT decoder and `BearerTokenAuthentication` for those with introspection.

You can query directly the SecurityContext of the request:

```
    final AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<? extends AbstractOAuth2Token> auth = (AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    final String bearerToken = auth.getToken().getTokenValue();
```

or have it auto-magically injected as `@Controller` method parameter:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/reflect-bearer-token")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String reflectBearerToken(AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<? extends AbstractOAuth2Token> auth) {
        return auth.getToken().getTokenValue();
}
```

First option (querying security-context) can be applied in a a feign `RequestInterceptor` to add an `Authorization` header with authenticated user Bearer to every request.